# Why does input() activate when not being called in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

In my code, I have a dictionary of values along with a key called `'custom'` which allows me to input an arbitrary value. When I print key values that are *NOT* `'custom'` it still hits the `input()` field:

```
Ip = {'argon':15.76,
      'neon':21.56,
      'krypton':14.00,
      'xenon':12.13,
      'helium':24.59,
      'hydrogen':15.42,
      'custom': float(input('Enter ionization potential (eV): '))}

print(Ip['argon'], Ip['helium'])
```

output:

```
Enter ionization potential (eV): 1
15.76 24.59
```

I was under the impression that keys and their associated values are kept suppressed until called, but clearly I misunderstand how dictionaries work.

A quick and dirty way of ameliorating this was to make a conditional statement, but there could be (for some reason) multiple `input()` dictionary definitions such that I'd have to hard-code a conditional statement for each one. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?

```
def func(key):
    
    if key == 'custom':
        Ip = {key:float(input('Enter ionization potential (eV): '))}

# Is there a way to remove the need for a conditional statement?
    else:
        Ip = {'argon':15.76,
              'neon':21.56,
              'krypton':14.00,
              'xenon':12.13,
              'helium':24.59,
              'hydrogen':15.42}
        
    return print(Ip[key])

func('argon')
```

output:

```
15.76
```

Comment: `I was under the impression that keys and their associated values are kept suppressed until called` What do you mean by `suppressed`?

Comment: I don't know if this is the right nomenclature, but I thought python would store `input()` as an object that would not activate when committing the dictionary to memory until it is called by the `key`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? You seem to have already realised that your assumption is wrong. A dict display is fully evaluated, including all its keys and values. Putting ``input()`` in a dict display is no different from putting it next to the dict.

Comment: When you create `Ip`, all expressions in the keys and values are evaluated in order to construct the dictionary.  If you want a value to be evaluated only when the key is accessed, make the value a function, and call that function after looking up the key.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think I clarified in the second part of the question, namely why do I need to put a conditional statement to make this work? Why is it the same thing as putting input next to the dict if is explictly assigned to a key?

Comment: @BoarGules That makes sense, I'll accept that as an answer if you post it

Comment: Sidenote: `print()` returns `None`, so `return print()` returns `None`. You want `return Ip[key]`

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the note, however this was just to show what I was running into

Comment: @t.o. I'm really not sure what to answer to that. The point of a *conditional* statement is to run code *conditionally*. So since you only want the code to run given some condition, yes, a conditional statement does that. If there isn't some conditional statement for protection (this includes also ``def`` and a few others) then it will run *unconditionally*; whether it's in a dict display or not is inconsequential for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** being called, as you've realized. When you define the dict, the call is evaluated and its result is inserted into the dict under `'custom'`, so in that example, `'custom': 1.0`. To avoid the call, make it a function instead.

Now that raises the question of how to have mixed types in a dict (floats and functions) and special-casing the functions. One way to get around that is to have two separate dicts: one with floats and a fallback one with functions. For example:

```
def func(key):
    ionization_potential = {
        'argon': 15.76,
        'neon': 21.56,
        'krypton': 14.00,
        'xenon': 12.13,
        'helium': 24.59,
        'hydrogen': 15.42}
    functions = {
        'custom': lambda: float(input('Enter ionization potential (eV): '))}
    try:
        v = ionization_potential[key]
    except KeyError:
        f = functions[key]
        v = f()
    return v
```

Demo:

```
>>> func('argon')
15.76
>>> func('custom')
Enter ionization potential (eV): 1
1.0
```

---

Lastly, if a key is not found in either dict, this will raise a `KeyError` from `KeyError`, so if I were you, I'd raise a `ValueError from None` in that case, since the problem is with the value of the argument:

```
try:
    f = functions[key]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError(f'key not found: {key!r}') from None
v = f()
```

Demo:

```
>>> func('foobar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: key not found: 'foobar'
```